# Replace elements in 2D array based on occurrence in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to replace elements in **Numpy** 2D arrays based on a condition that the element appears in some other `replacement` array

For example:

```
>>> main = np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 4))
>>> main
array([[1, 2, 4, 2],
   [3, 2, 3, 2],
   [4, 4, 2, 3]])
>>> repl = [2,3]
>>> main[main in repl] = -1
```

I would like to have all values in `repl` changed to -1, so I expect main to be:

```
[[1, -1, 4, -1],
[-1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 4, -1, -1]]
```

However a `ValueError` is raised while trying to have `in` inside the condition of replacement

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to create a flattened mask of all such occurrences and set those as `-1` in the flattened input, like so -

```
main.ravel()[np.in1d(main, repl)] = -1
```

Alternatively, we can use [`np.putmask`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.putmask.html) and thus avoid `np.ravel()` to avoid the explicit flattening, like so -

```
np.putmask(main, np.in1d(main, repl), -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a boolean mask and use it like this:

```
mask = np.logical_or(main == repl[0], main == repl[1])
main[mask] = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's any native `numpy` method for this, but in old fashion python you can do:

```
import numpy as np

main = np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 4))
repl = [2,3]
for k1, v1 in enumerate(main):
    for k2, v2 in enumerate(v1):
        if(v2 in repl):
            main[k1][k2] = -1
print(main)
```